# How to fix 'Could not open required defaults file: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini'

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed Xampp on my system. when I start Xampp_start.exe, the error as mentioned in the title comes up.
When I start Xampp_control.exe, it opens up and when i start mysql,it shuts down and error comes up.

I have tried to resolve the second issue by checking out all solutions available online including deleting irrelevant files in mysql\data but it still shows the same error.

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

Comment: Do you have C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini file in the file system?

Comment: Yes. It is a configuration file and it exists in that same file path as mentioned.